# Hibernate @Filter on @OneToMany relationship has no effect

Tags: hibernate, filter, querydsl

i'm using Hibernate to map my entities and QueryDSL for the queries. My entity Sector has many Familia and I want to filter only those that FMODIFICACION column is null. This is my Sector entity:

```
@FilterDef(name = "FAMILIA_FILTRO_FECHA")
@Entity
public class Sector {
    ...
    private List<Familia> familiasList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sector")
    @Filter(name = "FAMILIA_FILTRO_FECHA", condition = "FMODIFICACION IS NULL")
    public List<Familia> getFamiliasList() {
        return familiasList;
    }
    ...
}
```

And this is the query (using QueryDSL):

```
public List<Sector> getSectores() {

    //enable filter
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Filter filtroFamilia = session.enableFilter("FAMILIA_FILTRO_FECHA");

    //perform query
    QSector qSector = QSector.sector;
    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
    List<Sector> sectores = query.from(qSector).list(qSector);

    // disable filter
    session.disableFIlter("FAMILIA_FILTRO_FECHA");
    return sectores;
}
```

But this query is retrieving all the Familia. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! If filter is disabled in the same transaction it seems that has no effect in the query. Solution is just remove this line:

```
session.disableFIlter("FAMILIA_FILTRO_FECHA");
```